# How to extract multiple tokens from url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, url, token

http://staging.example.com/invitation/accept?invitation_token=**_86uiB3VskV5VATReut**9&study_token=**9d9ba0207a35971490aee5a11a40cc526b73137d047f1a8506a2b65e9e349706268cc7ab0ef6130a66913d01628b15f646e947d6b5dc4d874d675b4194ae6788**

How to extract invitation_token and study_token from above url ?
Tried using regex, but unable to extract it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in the API [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and use [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams):

```js
const str = 'http://staging.example.com/invitation/accept?invitation_token=_86uiB3VskV5VATReut9&study_token=9d9ba0207a35971490aee5a11a40cc526b73137d047f1a8506a2b65e9e349706268cc7ab0ef6130a66913d01628b15f646e947d6b5dc4d874d675b4194ae6788';
const url = new URL(str);

const tokens = {
  invitation: url.searchParams.get('invitation_token'),
  study: url.searchParams.get('study_token')
};

console.log(tokens);
```